# pandas: how to store a list in a sqlite db from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, sqlite

I have an excel table that looks like this:

```
   A |  B  | C |  D   | E
   1 |11|2 | 3 |4|5|6 | 7
   aa|ee   | s |34|7  | hi
```

I need to insert into a table in sqlite like this:

```
   A |       B       |    C    |         D          | E
   1 |[['11'],['2']] | [['3']] |[['4'],['5'],['6']] | 7
   aa|[['ee']]       | [['s']] |[['34'],['7']]      | hi
```

Only columns B C D are lists and the values could be separated by pipe.

I have written a function but it doesn't seem to give the right output:

```
   def on_pushButton_import_pressed(self):
       '''import eamena excel file into HFF System'''
       conn = Connection()
       conn_str = conn.conn_str()
    
       try:
          EXCEL_FILE_NAME = self.lineEdit_path_excel.text()
        
          wb = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE_NAME,skiprows=2)

          wb.to_sql('eamena_table',conn_str, if_exists='append',index=False)
       except Exception as e:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", str(e),QMessageBox.Ok)
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: Use a second table for your arrays with format `OriginalRowID | Value` for each value in each array.

Comment: Hi @forgetso I'm not undertand well what do you mean, but I'm looking the method 'at' and 'loc' in pandas to  convert in list each cell

Comment: I was meaning use a relational table model in SQL for storing relational data. If you want to keep it in pandas, just use `explode` to get the lists items into individual rows.